# How to serialize all int and boolean field to String with Jackson Json lib

Tags: java, json

I'm working on aria2 jsonrpc remote revoke, and I found out that all aria2 accept are strings value, like number 1 should be "1".

Although I can use JsonSerializer Annotation or use Module method, I think there should be an easy way which could apply "**Int to String Serializer**" to all of the fields of type int.

Could anyone give me a hint how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found an article that has described three steps to do that, and I thought that may be a through answer:

- Create a custom serializer extending the StdSerializer class
- Create an object of SimpleModule class, adding to it the custom serializer and specifying for which class it must be used
- Register the module on the ObjectMapper instance

ref: [Jackson: create and register a custom JSON serializer with StdSerializer and SimpleModule classes](http://www.davismol.net/2015/05/18/jackson-create-and-register-a-custom-json-serializer-with-stdserializer-and-simplemodule-classes/)